# Can't find UIView Subclass Template in XCode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, xcode-template

Did it disappear ? In XCode 3 it did exist. How to create a subview class in XCode 4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a template or class...?

A subview class can easily be created by File -> New -> Objective-c Class - > UIView Subclass ..->save

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem in adding just a normal UIView??

Comment: I'm following a tutorial made on xcode 3 wheras I'm on xcode 4 :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are choosing your xib file to be an iOS User Interface Empty file, not a Mac OS X one. In the latter, only NSView is available, not UIView.